# Dynamic Web Scraping not returning a complete NodeList

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, dom

Im trying to extract the content of a span tag in a dynamic html, but when i use the querySelectorAll, it returns only the _prevClass of the first element in the NodeList, nothing else.

My code:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');

const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
const url = 'https://mir4draco.com/price';

nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('span.amount')) // Should return a NodeList with 5 elements
    .end()
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });
```

The output:

```
{ '0': { _prevClass: 'amount' } }
```

[This is the output in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owV8M.png)

Comment: Are you logged in when this runs? I just visited the page and there's only the one element that exists under your query without being logged in, which would make sense.

Comment: no, im running this on a private tab, not logged in or extensions enabled

Comment: That's going to be you're problem then. If I visit the page (https://imgur.com/a/BnRAOhg), there is only one element that matches the query `span.amount`. You probably need to log in to see all the data you want.

Comment: i made the query `span.amount` in a private tab right now, it gave me the same result (https://imgur.com/SjBevwC), the login just show you some personal details, the data i want is available to everybody, logged in or not

Comment: See if you can check the console when you aren't getting the results you want. I am getting CORS errors from the page and it may be that your nightmare instance is too.

Comment: im not getting CORS errors, but im getting ReferenceError on the instance https://imgur.com/llYMGXP

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some tests i got a solution.

For some reason, this site only loads the tags i need after a few seconds when using an automation.

So, i've changed to puppeteer and used the slowMo parameter.

Now it works perfectly

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://mir4draco.com/price'

const precoDraco = async function () {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ slowMo: 10000 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    var prices = await page.evaluate(() => {
        var div = document.querySelectorAll('span.amount');

        var prices = "";
        div.forEach(element => {
            if (element != null) prices += element['innerText'] + " ";
        });
        return prices;
    })
    browser.close();
}
```

Now this works as it should